# azure aks failed to create

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-cli, azure-aks

I'm trying to create aks cluster with command

`az aks create --node-vm-size Standard_A2 --resource-group dev --name cluster --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys --debug`

It successfully creates the AD App for the cluster.

Anyway, it shows the error:

> Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: Service
>   principal clientID:  not found in Active Directory tenant
>   .

The clientId is the id of the app in the AD it has created.
I don't have even an idea where does it take the tenant guid.

So does somebody knows how can I solve the issue?

Info about my subscription: 
One account, one directory (Default), two subscriptions (trial expired, and bizspark one).

Answer (score 0):

So in my experience I had to specify clientId\clientSecret to the az aks command to be able to créate aks cluster. I dont think that's a permissions issue (because I definitely have permissions to créate new service principal on my subscriptions), but rather a bug.

```
az aks create --resource-group aks --name aks --location westeurope --service-principal guid --client-secret 'secret'
```

Comment: Still can't find the service principal I've just created in this weird Active Directory tenant. How to list them? How to change the AD tenant? http://prntscr.com/i0npf1

Comment: you can go to (on the portal) azure ad >> applications

Comment: Yep, you are right, and I can see both (the one that aks created for me and the one I've created manually) apps. But azure-cli still shows me that it can't find the app (sp) inside my AD tenant. That's weird cause I don't know what is that AD tenant id stands for.

Comment: azure ad tenant id - is the guid of your azure ad :) you can check if they match under azure ad > properties

Comment: That's what I've thought, but they don't match )) and I don't know why the cli creates the apps inside right directory, but uses the wrong id for the aks creation.

Comment: looks like a bug in the cli https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5219

Comment: like i said its most likely a bug ;) you should remove your picture as the clientId can be seen there ;)